# embedded jetty as proxy with rewrite rule versus basic authentication

Tags: apache, maven, jetty, url-rewriting, basic-authentication

So, in maven project I want to start jetty that will act as proxy for other location. I intend to use rewrite rule to serve some files locally, and some from target location. Additionally I need to add basic authentication for target location. Any hints how to do that?

Basically I want to replace following apache configuration with maven + jetty plugin for my project.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*/test.html - [L]
RewriteRule .*/test/.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^/(stuff|data)/(.*) http://production.com/$1/$2 [P]

SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*/stuff/.*" staticFileRequest
RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic njkhbHUHkj7678tHKhk78yKlk" env=staticFileRequest
```

Let's say that target location *http://production.com* has basic authentication with credentials *testUser:testPassword*

Any hints how to do that? I manage to do some rewrite working, but I have no luck with basic auth. I tried to mess with *org.eclipse.jetty.client.security.BasicAuthentication* in jetty configuration, but with no success.

I use Jetty 7.6.0.v20120127 now, but version is not that important for me.